# Javascript Self Adjusting Count-Down Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am trying to create an accurate countdown timer (accurate to the second), so that the second timer changes every second as opposed to lagging behind due to some other code I have.

I have a very limited understanding of how this works and I have attempted the following:

```
var seccount=100;
var seccounter=setInterval(sectimer, 1000);
var start = new Date().getTime();
function sectimer() {
  seccount--;
  elapsed = Math.ceil(seccount/100);
  var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) + seccount;
  window.setInterval(sectimer, (0 + diff));
  if (seccount < 0) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("sectimer").innerHTML=seccount+" seconds left!"
}
```

However, this timer seems to skip a few numbers some times. Is there any way to fix this? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Any count-down timer that is more accurate will do. I have been experimenting with the following timer that I have to try and make it more accurate, but I am not having much luck. Basically, it counts down every 1.1 seconds about (instead of every 1 second),

```
var seccount=100;
var seccounter=setInterval(sectimer, 1000);
function sectimer() {
  seccount--;
  if (seccount < 0) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("sectimer").innerHTML=seccount+" seconds left!";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval()` as well as `setTimeout()`? Try it with just `setTimeout()`. (Also, you seem to have left off the final `}` of your function, and the indenting makes it looks like the `.innerHTML` update happens outside the function.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Looks like I was missing the final `}`, thanks! Though, now it doesn't display at all.

Comment: @Xufox it's actually not needed in the function. I have taken it out above.

Comment: You need to add the final `}` *after* the `...innerHTML = ...` line. Also, try removing the `setInterval()` line and just call `sectimer()` to start things off.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried removing the setInterval(), but that makes it so the countdown isn't displayed.

Comment: After removing `setInterval()` you'd need to call your function once with `sectimer()` to get it going. It then uses `setTimeout()` to (sort of) call itself (as per an earlier, pre-edit version of your question). The edited version of your code with `setInterval()` *inside* the function doesn't make sense at all because then every second you'd be creating an additional interval.

Comment: @nnnnnn I edited above to reflect what I am searching for. Doing this seemed to get the timer to show, but it is still not very accurate. If I watch a timer that is separate to this, it becomes a few seconds off by the end of the 100 seconds. I am just looking for a way to make an accurate countdown timer.

Comment: You could try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qb7kc0xy/ - or you could go for much more frequent updates that are based on the actual current time rather than subtracting from the last tick: https://jsfiddle.net/qb7kc0xy/1/

Comment: @nnnnnn The second one is more what I was trying to do. It is much more accurate now. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/